# Having problems finding the height of my first Binary Search Tree in JS

Tags: javascript, height, binary-search-tree

Here is my constructor function as well as my 'add' method...

```
function BinarySearchTree(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.right = null;
    this.left = null;
  }

BinarySearchTree.prototype.add = function(value) {
    if (value < this.value) {
      if (this.left) this.left.add(value);
      else this.left = new BinarySearchTree(value);
    }
  
    if (value > this.value) {
      if (this.right) this.right.add(value);
      else this.right = new BinarySearchTree(value);
    }
  };
```

Here is the 'getNodeHeight' method I am trying to make...

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.getNodeHeight = function(node) {
    if (node.value === null) {
      return -1;
    }
    return Math.max(this.getNodeHeight(node.left), this.getNodeHeight(node.right)) + 1;
  }
```

And here are the test cases I am running...

```
binarySearchTree = new BinarySearchTree(5);
binarySearchTree.left = new BinarySearchTree(3);
binarySearchTree.left.left = new BinarySearchTree(1);
binarySearchTree.getNodeHeight(this);
```

Every time I log the last one to the console I get "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')". I believe I may be using the 'this' keyword incorrectly... but I've tried messing with it and can't figure it out!

Any tips, tricks, or help would be greatly appreciated... Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the first line of your `getNodeHeight` function when it's called on `node.right` (which is `null`). `null` doesn't have a `value` property. The same error will occur if you evaluate

```
null.value
```

Fix this by changing

```
if (node.value === null) ...
```

to

```
if (!node) ...
```

On further investigation, the use of the `this` keyword in `binarySearchTree.getNodeHeight(this)` is likely returning a reference to your Window object instead of the `binarySearchTree`. Try calling the method by way of

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.getNodeHeight(binarySearchTree)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hmm... I tried what you said but I still get "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')" Am I using 'this' properly?

Comment: I updated my answer. Use `if (!node)` instead of `if (node === null)`.

Comment: Nope... still the same error! Thanks though!

Comment: No. I will help you! :) I think the actual problem is likely that you're attempting to refer to `binarySearchTree` using the `this` keyword, but that probably returns a reference to something else (maybe the Window object). Try calling the function by `BinarySearchTree.prototype.getNodeHeight(binarySearchTree)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues, one that was pointed out by @Austin regarding the check on whether the input value is null.

The other issue is that there is no default value for `getNodeHeight`. For this I'm assuming that you're expecting the default behavior to find the height of the whole tree. Passing in `this` to `getNodeHeight` is passing in the context where you are creating the BinarySearchTree - not the instance.

```js
function BinarySearchTree(value) {
  this.value = value;
  this.right = null;
  this.left = null;
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype.add = function(value) {
  if (value < this.value) {
    if (this.left) this.left.add(value);
    else this.left = new BinarySearchTree(value);
  }

  if (value > this.value) {
    if (this.right) this.right.add(value);
    else this.right = new BinarySearchTree(value);
  }
};

BinarySearchTree.prototype.getNodeHeight = function(node = this) {
  if (node === null) {
    return -1;
  }
  return Math.max(this.getNodeHeight(node.left), this.getNodeHeight(node.right)) + 1;
}

const binarySearchTree = new BinarySearchTree(5);
binarySearchTree.left = new BinarySearchTree(3);
binarySearchTree.left.left = new BinarySearchTree(1);
console.log(binarySearchTree.getNodeHeight());
```